# How to get icollection data sending from web api to My object class?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

i am receiving the data from web api but dont know how to Get this Icollection stuff to my Model object

Api Controller

public IHttpActionResult Campaigndetails(int id)
        {

```
        IList<CampaignViewModel> list = null;
        using (IdonateEntities2 entities = new IdonateEntities2())
        {

            list = entities.Campaigns.Include(x => x.Donors).Select(x =>
                new CampaignViewModel()
                {
                    campaign_id = x.campaign_id,
                    title = x.title,
                    description = x.description,
                    amount = x.amount,
                    image = x.image,
                    raised_amount = x.raised_amount,
                    category_id = x.category_id,
                    user_id = x.user_id,
                    Donor = x.Donors.Select(d=> new DonorViewModel()
                    {
                        donor_id = d.donor_id,
                        donor_name = d.donor_name,
                        donated_amount = d.donated_amount,
                        campaign_id = d.campaign_id,
                        payment_id = d.payment_id
                    }).ToList()







                }).ToList().Where(x => x.campaign_id == id).ToList();

            return Ok(list);
        }
```

Campaign Controller:

public ActionResult Detail(int id)
        {

```
        List<Category> category = new List<Category>();
        string text = string.Empty;


        var request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:49210/api/campaign/campaigndetails/"+ id);
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            text = sr.ReadToEnd();
            category = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Category>>(text);

        }

        return View(category);
    }
```

My Model Classes:

public class Category
    {

```
    public Category()
    {
        this.Donors = new HashSet<DonorViewModel>();
    }

    public int campaign_id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public int amount { get; set; }
    public int zipcode { get; set; }
    public int category_id { get; set; }
    public int user_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable <int> raised_amount { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DonorViewModel> Donors { get; set; }




}

public class DonorViewModel
{
    public int donor_id { get; set; }
    public string donor_name { get; set; }
    public int donated_amount { get; set; }
    public int campaign_id { get; set; }
    public int payment_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> user_id { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

    }
```

text is showing all data received by web api but category object showing no data in Donor i want to receive it and passed to my view to show

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/sfabT6U   https://imgur.com/Nxn3VOP

Comment: Why are you making an http call inside your `Detail(int id)` method to a web api endpoint instead of getting the data directly thorugh your `IdonateEntities2` context?

Comment: @Marco Because i have two project one is for Webapi and the other one i am accessing my data from these both are different projects

Comment: If you refactor your entities into its own project, without the web api, you could just reference it. Your current approach will fail, once your url changes. Just add a class library to your solution and put your data access logic in there. Then you have it available to both: your mvc and your web api project.

Comment: @Marco sorry but i dont understand what you just said :(

Comment: You are making your life too hard. Your `IdonateEntities2` should be in its own project, so you can reference them in all of your projects in your solution. this way you don't need to call your web api inside your mvc action method, but can access your database or data source directly.

Comment: @Marco yeah i know but the issue is the requirements, my requirement is to separate the client and server side so that is why i made two separate project one for the Web api which is connected to my Database and the other one is client side to whom i am sending all the data through api!